# Adding string to a file (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to append some string to every line in file, content of file:(list.txt)

```
songs
flower
```

what I wanna do:   (!and I don't want to add these to file(list.txt) just want to print in terminal)

```
newsongs
oldsongs
newflower
oldflower
```

code I tried:

```
file = open("list.txt")

for i in file:
   new = "new"+i
   print(new)

for i in file:
   old = "old"+i
   print(old)
```

o/p I get :

```
newsongs
newflower
```

what I'm expecting:

```
newsongs
oldsongs
newflower
oldflower
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file object is an iterator, which means that once it's exhausted (iterated over in a for-loop), it's empty. You should be able to go back to the beginning of the file by using the `seek()` method of the file object between the two loops:

```py
fin = open(infile)

for line in fin:
  print(line)  # do sth here

fin.seek(0)

for line in fin:
  print(line)  # do sth else here
```

But this doesn't seem to be what you want. You just need to create two new strings for every file line read and print them out:

```py
for line in fin:
  print('something +', line)
  print('something else +', line)
```

Comment: it works now ..thanks and can get the exactly like what i explained before > o/p: newsong,newflower,oldsong,oldflower it wouls be better if get like this: newsong,oldsong,newflower,oldflower

Comment: Now i'm getting whitespace -> new song, old song ...how to get rid of this ?

Comment: By string concatenation, as you did it in your code: `print('new' + line)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
with open("list.txt", "r") as file:
    org_lines = [i.strip() for i in file.readlines() if i.strip()]
output = []
for i in org_lines:
    output.append('new'+i+'\nold'+i)
with open("new_file.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(output))
```

First read all the lines and get them into a list `org_lines`. Now for each item in that list (which is eventually a line from the original file), append a new string which has `'new'` concatenated before the line followed by `'old'` concatenated before the line into another new list. Now join this newly created list with newline and write the whole string into another file.